# ggrepel changes plot limits and does it differently for multiple runs of the same code

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I am using ggrepel to write some names in a bidimensional plot. There are also a few extra annotations, and I have noticed that, for the exact same code, for some runs the two overlap and for some runs they don't. Specially bad is that it actually changes my plot margins and does it on a word that doesn't clash with any other and therefore ggrepel shouldn't move around.

If I use geom_text instead of geom_text_repel the problem goes away, or if I set a seed too, but for various reasons I can do neither. I understand that ggrepel must have a random component to shuffle names around, but I don't understand how this can change my plot limits.
Here is a sample code, you need to run it several times to see the difference (which you'll see on the top right, where Sirius B. clashes with "Controvers" for some runs and not for others).

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggrepel)
#set.seed(1)
```

```
# sample data
a = c(5, 6, 7, 6, 24, 4, 3, 5, 26, 8, 13, 4, 8, 11, 0, 11, 7, 5, 3, 10, 11, 8)
b = c(16 ,19 ,17 ,17 ,21 ,11 ,8 ,11 ,32 ,11 ,24 ,14 ,11 ,17 ,14 ,24 ,14 ,11 ,12 ,18 ,12 ,21)
noms = c("Hermione G." ,"Neville L." ,"Luna L." ,"Ron W." ,"Ginny W." ,"Percy W." ,"Lilly P." ,"Seamus F." ,"Sirius B." ,"Dean T." ,"Draco M." ,"Harry P." ,"Xo X." ,"Viktor K." ,"Hannah A." ,"Susan B." ,"Pansy P." ,"Fleur D." ,"Cormac M." ,"Cedric D." ,"Fay D." ,"Maisy R.")

# this is just to reproduce my exact results
df = cbind.data.frame(a, b, noms)
df[, 1] = scale(df[, 1])
df[, 2] = scale(df[, 2])

max_y = max(max(df[, 1]), abs(min(df[, 1])))
max_x = max(max(df[, 2]), abs(min(df[, 2])))
```

```
# actual plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = df[, 2], y = df[, 1], label = noms)) + 
  geom_text_repel(fontface = "bold") + 
  geom_text(aes(x = max_x - 0.25, y = max_y - 0.15, label = "Controvers"), fontface = "italic", angle = 40) +
  xlim(c(-max_x - .1, max_x + .1)) + 
  ylim(c(-max_y - .1, max_y + .1)) +
  theme_void() + 
  ggsave(file = "file.pdf", dpi = 1200, width = 25, height = 20, units = "cm")
```

I use R 3.5.3, ggplot2 3.1.1 and ggrepel 0.8.1 on a Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geom_text_repel` does indeed have a random component and it changes the plot's limits based on the text positions it creates. You can control for both using the arguments `seed` (gets passed to `set.seed`), `xlim`, and `ylim` (defaults are `NA`) inside of `geom_text_repel` call.

This creates the same plot all the time within your plot limits:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = df[, 2], y = df[, 1], label = noms)) + 
  geom_text_repel(fontface = "bold", seed = 1, 
                  xlim = c(-max_x - .1, max_x + .1),
                  ylim = c(-max_y - .1, max_y + .1)) + 
  geom_text(aes(x = max_x - 0.25, y = max_y - 0.15, label = "Controvers"), fontface = "italic", angle = 40) +
  xlim(c(-max_x - .1, max_x + .1)) + 
  ylim(c(-max_y - .1, max_y + .1)) +
  theme_void() + 
  ggsave(file = "file.pdf", dpi = 1200, width = 25, height = 20, units = "cm")
```

Comment: Oh, I should have read the ggrepel documentation a little more thoroughly... Thanks a lot!